# How to display both Name and ID of a program in Dropdownlist control

Tags: c#, database, drop-down-menu

My project display's program names from the database into dropdownlist and each program has a ID. I want to display both name and id in the dropdownlist so that they can be differenciated from each other.
eg: 'california lifeline (CLA)' 
where 'california lifeline' is the name of the program and the id is 'CLA'. I have created a stored procedure which displays data based on the program ID.

This the code of my dropdownlist control.

```
private void LoadProgramName()
{
    _drp_program = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("bodyuc$drp_program");

    dsprg = rProxy.GlobalFetchFromDB(strCountyName, "DBO.oea_sp_get_onoff_programNames");

    _drp_program.DataSource = dsprg;
    _drp_program.DataTextField = "PROG_NAME";
    _drp_program.DataValueField = "PROGRAM_ID";
    _drp_program.DataBind(); ;

    ListItem lst_prog = new ListItem();
    lst_prog.Value = "";
    lst_prog.Text = "--Select One--";
    _drp_program.Items.Insert(0, lst_prog);
    _drp_program.Items.Insert(1, "ALL");

}
```

BTW, the dropdown is a part of pagecontrol.

Help is Appriceated.

Comment: Hey @user I read a few of your questions and the things we are programming seem to be similar, both for non-profits. Just thought that was a bit odd. If it's not too much info to give, what company do your work for?

Answer (score 0):

If your GlobalFetchFromDB() returns instances of an object which you can "extend" as a partial class, then I'd add a "helper" property to the class that formats your displayed string.

One advantage to this is that the format can be dependent on the values of other properties in the instance.

For example:

```
public partial class ProgramItem
{
    public string DisplayName { get { return PROG_NAME.ToUpper(); } }
}
```

Then use `_drp_program.DataTextField = "DisplayName";`

An alternative is to construct a class that encapsulates the returned items and adds the DisplayName as a decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding _drp_program to dsprg, loop through the results in dsprg and add each item individually.

```
foreach(dsprgObject in dsprg)
{
   _drp_program.Items.add(new ListItem(dsprgObject .ColA + " " + dsprgObject .ColB, dsprgObject.PROGRAM_ID));
}
```

Comment: That's OK only if you don't need to later access the SelectedItem as an instance of the object returned from GlobalFetchFromDB(). You've lost all of the information from the objects returned, other than the ID value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
_drp_program.DataSource = from item in dsprg
                            select new
                            {
                                PROG_NAME = string.Format("{0}({1})", item.PROG_NAME, item.PROGRAM_ID) ,
                                PROGRAM_ID = item.PROGRAM_ID
                            };
```

instead of

```
 _drp_program.DataSource = dsprg;
```

Comment: It's giving me this error message: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.DataSet'.  'Select' not found.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the fastest way is to concatenate ID and NAME in an SQL query (but you're using an sp so that's a bit difficult). Also, since you binding your control in code, you can concatenate ID and Name in code and populate your dropdownlist manually (either by calling Items.Insert or by binding your dropdown to a collection which members have a field/property that contains the concatenated value). AFAIK, you can only specify a field/property name for DataTextField and DataValueField, no expressions etc...